# How to keep only head changes in a git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase

I'm currently in the middle of a lengthy rebase going through a dozen or so commits. I've structured things in my dev process such that only the changes from `HEAD` is what I want to keep - all other conflicts (e.g. commit hash `b06a1dd`) should be deleted.

Is there a way to simply remove all changes related to the `>>>>>>> b06a1dd` and keep the changes that Git will label `<<<<<<< HEAD` in one fell swoop, so I don't have to keep typing `git rebase --continue`, deal with more conflicts from more commit hashes, and only keep the `HEAD` changes?

Comment: In other words, can I just keep the HEAD changes and not have to open up the files containing conflicts in my text editor?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

If you are willing to start the rebase over (`git rebase --abort`), then this should do what you need:

```
git rebase -X ours upstream
```

where `upstream` is the branch you are rebasing onto.

As noted in [this answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/25576672/2747593) and elsewhere, the `ours` vs. `theirs` labels are slightly more confusing for rebasing than for merging. After starting a rebase, Git creates an anonymous branch and starts applying commits to it. Since `ours` means "keep changes from the current branch", that current branch will be `HEAD`, which contains `upstream` and any changes already applied by `rebase`.

Comment: Is there any way of picking `ours` or `theirs` changes at *specific* conflicts when there's already a rebase under way?

Comment: @AlexandroSánchez you can use git checkout --ours, just remember that ours and theirs are swapped during rebase, see https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---ours

Comment: I get forced to cherry pick:
The previous cherry-pick is now empty, possibly due to conflict resolution.
If you wish to commit it anyway, use:

    git commit --allow-empty

Otherwise, please use 'git cherry-pick --skip'
interactive rebase in progress; onto c0f562d
Last commands done (13 commands done):
   pick f3db26ce36 Bluh
   pick bb461e5aaa Bloh
Next commands to do (35 remaining commands):
   pick fd1c6d5087 Blih
   pick 6db57302e4 Bleh
You are currently rebasing branch 'my_branch' on 'c0f562d755'

nothing to commit, working tree clean
Could not apply bb461e5aaa... Blah

Comment: @JosePaez: I'm not sure what the context here is or what your question is.  AFAICT it doesn't seem to be the same as this question though, so if you're still having this problem, please [ask a new question](/questions/ask), linking to this one if it's related.  If you do ask a new question, feel free to post the link here so I'll see it.

Answer (score 17):

For the sake of completeness, this is what I learn from the previous answer and comments in current Q&A (credit goes to their authors):

- If you are willing to start over and **choose same side for ALL the commits**, the current chosen answer `git rebase --abort` and then `git rebase -X ours upstream` can do the trick.
- But I guess in practice you won't want to blindly use either `ours` or `theirs` without looking into each commits. You would want to **make a case-by-case decision for each commit**, when "in the middle of a lengthy rebase". So, your actual options will be:

  1. To use the upstream:

     ```
     git checkout --ours path/to/a/specific/file
     git add path/to/a/specific/file
     ```

     or even better, in this case you simply use this:

     ```
     git reset HEAD path/to/a/specific/file
     ```
  2. Use your feature branch:

     ```
     git checkout --theirs path/to/a/specific/file
     ```
  3. or do it in the manual way to address each `<<<< ... ==== ... >>>>` in your editor.

PS: [The `ours` and `theirs` have special meaning when doing rebase.](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout---ours):

> Note that during git rebase and git pull --rebase, ours and theirs may appear swapped; --ours gives the version from the branch the changes are rebased onto, while --theirs gives the version from the branch that holds your work that is being rebased.
>
> This is because rebase is used in a workflow that treats the history at the remote as the shared canonical one, and treats the work done on the branch you are rebasing as the third-party work to be integrated, and you are temporarily assuming the role of the keeper of the canonical history during the rebase. As the keeper of the canonical history, you need to view the history from the remote as ours (i.e. "our shared canonical history"), while what you did on your side branch as theirs (i.e. "one contributor’s work on top of it").

Comment: It failed miserably for me, I used the "git reset HEAD path/to/a/specific/file" for every file, finished and went to start the server and got "There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: syntax error, unexpected <<, expecting keyword_end - <<<<<<< HEAD...."

Comment: @JosePaez Sorry to hear that. Unless you have the mood to redo it, reproduce it, and pinpoint the reason, it is hard to give a specific comment here. It could be an accidental `git add path/to/that/Gemfile`, or some equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, in my case the branch I was rebasing to was a new branch (I had just created it and therefore was empty) so I just needed a good old pull:

```
git rebase --abort && git pull origin my/remote_branch
```